# React with Typescript -- Generics while using React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I am trying to create a generic component where a user can pass the a custom `OptionType` to the component to get type checking all the way through. This component also required a `React.forwardRef`.

I can get it to work without a forwardRef. Any ideas? Code below:

**WithoutForwardRef.tsx**

```
export interface Option<OptionValueType = unknown> {
  value: OptionValueType;
  label: string;
}

interface WithoutForwardRefProps<OptionType> {
  onChange: (option: OptionType) => void;
  options: OptionType[];
}

export const WithoutForwardRef = <OptionType extends Option>(
  props: WithoutForwardRefProps<OptionType>,
) => {
  const { options, onChange } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {options.map((opt) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              onChange(opt);
            }}
          >
            {opt.label}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**WithForwardRef.tsx**

```
import { Option } from './WithoutForwardRef';

interface WithForwardRefProps<OptionType> {
  onChange: (option: OptionType) => void;
  options: OptionType[];
}

export const WithForwardRef = React.forwardRef(
  <OptionType extends Option>(
    props: WithForwardRefProps<OptionType>,
    ref?: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>,
  ) => {
    const { options, onChange } = props;
    return (
      <div>
        {options.map((opt) => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                onChange(opt);
              }}
            >
              {opt.label}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  },
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { WithoutForwardRef, Option } from './WithoutForwardRef';
import { WithForwardRef } from './WithForwardRef';

interface CustomOption extends Option<number> {
  action: (value: number) => void;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Without Forward Ref</h3>
      <h4>Basic</h4>
      <WithoutForwardRef
        options={[{ value: 'test', label: 'Test' }, { value: 1, label: 'Test Two' }]}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Does type inference on the type of value in the options
          console.log('BASIC', option);
        }}
      />
      <h4>Custom</h4>
      <WithoutForwardRef<CustomOption>
        options={[
          {
            value: 1,
            label: 'Test',
            action: (value) => {
              console.log('ACTION', value);
            },
          },
        ]}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Intellisense works here
          option.action(option.value);
        }}
      />
      <h3>With Forward Ref</h3>
      <h4>Basic</h4>
      <WithForwardRef
        options={[{ value: 'test', label: 'Test' }, { value: 1, label: 'Test Two' }]}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Does type inference on the type of value in the options
          console.log('BASIC', option);
        }}
      />
      <h4>Custom (WitForwardRef is not generic here)</h4>
      <WithForwardRef<CustomOption>
        options={[
          {
            value: 1,
            label: 'Test',
            action: (value) => {
              console.log('ACTION', value);
            },
          },
        ]}
        onChange={(option) => {
          // Intellisense SHOULD works here
          option.action(option.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the `App.tsx`, it says the `WithForwardRef` component is not generic. Is there a way to achieve this?

Example repo: https://github.com/jgodi/generics-with-forward-ref

Thanks!

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Creating a generic component as output of `React.forwardRef` is not directly possible <sup>1</sup> (see bottom). There are some alternatives though - let's simplify your example a bit for illustration:

```
type Option<O = unknown> = { value: O; label: string; }
type Props<T extends Option<unknown>> = { options: T[] }

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: "la1", flag: true }, 
  { value: 2, label: "la2", flag: false }
]
```

Choose variants (1) or (2) for simplicity. (3) will replace `forwardRef` by usual props. With (4) you globally chance `forwardRef` type definitions once in the app.

[Playground variants 1, 2, 3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=19&ssc=70&pln=17&pc=1#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-I-rQSD+GgACEzJwOCalwIKHRiOxOp+CguEiEggiGXAcr9pKwJyvICDFKmkRGDgobGuuO5ChCwIAIIwH4wBuDySBxDZt73j2l64nAAA+cDERQFAVp53n+H5aRZMAWR+cAFAwAAtAEAn0jW+4gux6RwBoSBCHAEaxIMhABEg6RNvAE7LFc3bCqKUDihZQ4gWO7YalOWRmV1A6WfIDrns6OJuk1cCft+v5tQBwWpi1bVwbB5SyghhBBshhCoeWpLklclIAOpQAmnIMqSc2SW2aoastbm9p13WDgQw5KiqA3gMS5KJGl+5gK4aANXAbiVfSWSvjRKABPABq5HI+TaHohh5Q94F-WAVwCCkkCwHAcPwJdCaiFAWpzrqi76ttBJ4AdRCqWp3CdAwtgzhusRbruTNAoQx7CvaZ5OmFbo3kB2PSXjuBqeC7MwLtBD7YLBBHS+-wLT+L2AXeqbk2AlMadt3hbYa8EAurasoXAaHMhWADMlJaSTHQwGwRVVTEnLePQqClRAILvWNhCMlrb7UhqTvU7perLrkq6muuFrxIY-PW8Cx4EKejoXk+ksMMFM6+v6iHM6GuDVVGcFxgmSZAemmbZncFB5gW7rFo0pZeqT81fj+scrUBE6x5tmZm0wzO24d9v6EAA)

[Playground variant 4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeA5FEJAEwFEAPCGYNAYQnAgDskmYBfOAMygbgCIoqDPwBQo4kjQAbFELggIxAK7SkAoehj9couHAD0BuADFocACoBlOGFkBPAOa9lTYthj2w60JFgBnOBYSOBgIOAAjdWV-ELCFFABrdRgAC3V-Qjt1NAYwYDUAOj1DYwBJJjhpCDQUaThJADdsewhlOFrKmPUzKAB3OUliZC5sZC1SNSI2MaQuAEEYGChgCOUYJEDiYCEMaXti-S5XDGBmbmgBqGG5gB4LbAAFOABeXHYAPgAKEv0hNyQUAAXHAvmBeGB-CDHtghFwQb5oDAvoJhNoAJSFXpXIYje4fdGvD5wRGwFGaESY8YYSZIabwAA%20QVU0hK6JBYIhULgzwAZCTGGTUVp%20FS5otlqt1pt8YSXsTScjhZTCtSYLT6XAmUwWaJ2OJgGxAVx0OpHlz8bp9CgQRY9eJckx-PALCgImpsYMRsgAVBXnB7k9-ThPj99OCIJDoRbHh9MCU4SC1VjLoMSHiLB9RHLibdto0PjgI5DCih2LcDPms6JHc7LG6PanriN6OB-cmuE2blwvq73UhPc25j7JFB0eIjHAABIQRqAuCz%20f8FA6YuBFBuIJUGgpdI7OCOViAmihLxIUSTkw7OvLnTAQLOlZMRzYWKO4jMkBRKA15h1%20ZgGA-pfDmoIlLcWb6Po9wNgOXYtnkcAoC8-CdhAOgGMSvwBn2jb9F6cytkByE4AAzJwmFwOBmHZgA3OIvawYO3ZEUh65MPYmLbP4dgoPYBBEKIjH9sxCFtiggQCSQFDbnQeTMKwMBcfevH8YQ564XB%20FDlwRGFNxqlSaUDQQJsTAAOTwH00CJKe3gALR9Pe6gbvYihCOIQA)

#### 1. Use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) ("cast")

```js
// Given render function (input) for React.forwardRef
const FRefInputComp = <T extends Option>(p: Props<T>, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) =>
  <div ref={ref}> {p.options.map(o => <p>{o.label}</p>)} </div>

// Cast the output
const FRefOutputComp1 = React.forwardRef(FRefInputComp) as
  <T extends Option>(p: Props<T> & { ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement> }) => ReactElement

const Usage11 = () => <FRefOutputComp1 options={options} ref={myRef} />
// options has type { value: number; label: string; flag: boolean; }[] 
// , so we have made FRefOutputComp generic!
```

This works, as the return type of `forwardRef` in principle is a [plain function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9d56fee/types/react/index.d.ts#L800). We just need a generic function type shape. You might add an extra type to make the assertion simpler:

```
type ForwardRefFn<R> = <P={}>(p: P & React.RefAttributes<R>) => ReactElement |null
// `RefAttributes` is built-in type with ref and key props defined
const Comp12 = React.forwardRef(FRefInputComp) as ForwardRefFn<HTMLDivElement>
const Usage12 = () => <Comp12 options={options} ref={myRef} />
```

#### 2. Wrap forwarded component

```
const FRefOutputComp2 = React.forwardRef(FRefInputComp)
// ↳ T is instantiated with base constraint `Option<unknown>` from FRefInputComp

export const Wrapper = <T extends Option>({myRef, ...rest}: Props<T> & 
  {myRef: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>}) => <FRefOutputComp2 {...rest} ref={myRef} />

const Usage2 = () => <Wrapper options={options} myRef={myRef} />
```

#### 3. Omit `forwardRef` alltogether

Use a [custom ref prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) instead. This one is my favorite - simplest alternative, a [legitimate way in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578570/value-of-using-react-forwardref-vs-custom-ref-prop/60237948#60237948) and doesn't need `forwardRef`.

```
const Comp3 = <T extends Option>(props: Props<T> & {myRef: Ref<HTMLDivElement>}) 
  => <div ref={myRef}> {props.options.map(o => <p>{o.label}</p>)} </div>
const Usage3 = () => <Comp3 options={options} myRef={myRef} />
```

#### 4. Use global type augmentation

Add following code *once* in your app, perferrably in a separate module `react-augment.d.ts`:

```
import React from "react"

declare module "react" {
  function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(
    render: (props: P, ref: ForwardedRef<T>) => ReactElement | null
  ): (props: P & RefAttributes<T>) => ReactElement | null
}
```

This will [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) React module type declarations, overriding `forwardRef` with a new [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) type signature. Tradeoff: component properties like `displayName` now need a type assertion.

---

### <sup>1</sup> Why does the original case not work?

[`React.forwardRef`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9d56fee/types/react/index.d.ts#L800) has following type:

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): 
  ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

So this function takes a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) component-like [render function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9d56fee/types/react/index.d.ts#L559-L572) `ForwardRefRenderFunction`, and returns the final component with type `ForwardRefExoticComponent`. These two are just function type declarations [with additional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) `displayName`, `defaultProps` etc.

Now, there is a TypeScript 3.4 feature called [higher order function type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) akin to [Higher-Rank Types](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/115/higher-rank-and-higher-kinded-types). It basically allows you to propagate free type parameters (generics from the input function) on to the outer, calling function - `React.forwardRef` here -, so the resulting function component is still generic.

But this feature can only work with plain function types, as Anders Hejlsberg explains in [[1]](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30650#issuecomment-478258803), [[2]](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30650#issuecomment-486680485):

> We only make higher order function type inferences when the source and target types are both pure function types, i.e. types with a single call signature *and no other members*.

Above solutions will make `React.forwardRef` work with generics again.

Comment: Note: There is a 4th alternative: augment react types of `forwardRef` to use generic functions (similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389122/5669456) with `React.memo`)

Comment: @ford04 Thanks a lot for your solution! Very clean explanation. For future reference, I created a small [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-custom-button-typescript-example-rdtrz?file=/src/App.tsx:1987-2470) so people can see your solutions in action.

Comment: @ford04 I also tried to implement your 4th solution based on the example given [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386614/how-to-use-props-with-generics-with-react-memo/60389122#60389122), but I was not able to find the right syntax. Did you during your work also find the right syntax for overloading the React.ForwardRef function such that it can take in a generic function? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @arcety I just tried that on a local environment - seems to work so far. Take a look [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0yRN) and paste that into local env as well (playground currently doesn't like TS + React at least for me). Also note the return type `(props: P & RefAttributes<T>) => ReactElement | null` instead of `ForwardRefExoticComponent`. A function type with properties in addition to a [single call signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) did infer type parameters to `unknown`, I guess that's how its implemented.  Cheers

Comment: @ford04 Wow thanks a lot for your answer! It works perfectly inside my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-custom-button-typescript-example-rdtrz?file=/src/App.tsx:5986-6003). I was using the ForwardRefExoticComponent type when I tried it myself. Thanks a lot for explaining why that does not work.

Comment: @arcety glad it works. This alternative should be fine, if you don't need types for additional properties like `defaultProps` etc. And you only need to do it once in the app. I updated answer with a bit better explanation.

Comment: @ford04 Wow, thanks a lot! Your answer now gives me a clear understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Hi @ford04,I went with the fourth solution (augment TS type) and I'm not able to do `MyComponent.displayName = "MyComponent"` anymore.

Do you have a solution for me please ?

Comment: For anyone using the global type augmentation solution (i.e. the fourth solution), I've been adding display name like so: `(MyComponent as NamedExoticComponent).displayName = "MyComponent";`. The `NamedExoticComponent` type is exported from "react".

Comment: @ford04 I followed your steps, but getting a small error. Can you please help? https://ibb.co/HPzsKhX

Comment: I was fighting component prop typings for days until I realized it was the forwardRef gobbling them up. This comment saved my sanity, really appreciated.

Comment: This answer is fantastic but in the end I stumbled upon a writeup of this answer here https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs which made the `type augmentation` example more clear to me trying to properly wrap the new Next 13.4 next/link component forwarding props etc 

Comment: I never barely use displayName, defaultProps or propTypes. The tradeoff is really fine.

Answer (score 23):

I discovered this question from reading [this blog post](https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/09/20/react-i-love-you.html#i-want-none-of-this), and I think there is a more straight-forward way of accomplishing this than the current [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473012/2089675) answer has proposed:

First we define an interface to hold the type of the component using something called a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) in typescript:

```
interface WithForwardRefType extends React.FC<WithForwardRefProps<Option>>  {
  <T extends Option>(props: WithForwardRefProps<T>): ReturnType<React.FC<WithForwardRefProps<T>>>
}
```

*Notice how the function signature itself is declared as generic, not the interface - this is the key to making this work. The interface also extends React.FC in order to expose some useful Component properties such as `displayName`, `defaultProps`, etc.*

Next we just supply that interface as the type of our component, and **without having to specify the type of the props**, we can pass that component to `forwardRef`, and the rest is history...

```
export const WithForwardRef: WithForwardRefType = forwardRef((
  props,
  ref?: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>,
) => {
  const { options, onChange } = props;
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {options.map((opt) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              onChange(opt);
            }}
          >
            {opt.label}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-forwardref-component-ch7hqp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)

---

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73795451/2089675

Comment: Can confirm this works! I think it's more elegant as we don't augment forwardRef that can change in the future.

Comment: In my case I wasn't using an Option that T would extends but directly a custom type on my component props, so just replaced Option by unknown on the first occurrence and removed it from the extends

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React, { forwardRef, ForwardedRef } from 'react';
import {
  DeepPartial,
  FieldValues,
  FormProvider,
  SubmitHandler,
  useForm,
  Resolver,
} from 'react-hook-form';

import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

type GenericOnSubmit<T extends FieldValues> = (
  data: T,
  event?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent
) => void;

type FormProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<T>;
  defaultValues?: DeepPartial<T>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  schema?: Yup.ObjectSchema<Yup.AnyObject, Yup.AnyObject, Yup.AnyObject, ''>;
  ref?: ForwardedRef<HTMLFormElement>;
};

interface WithForwardRefType<T extends FieldValues>
  extends React.FC<FormProps<T>> {
  <T extends FieldValues>(props: FormProps<T>): ReturnType<
    React.FC<FormProps<T>>
  >;
}

export const Form: WithForwardRefType<FieldValues> = forwardRef<
  HTMLFormElement,
  FormProps<FieldValues>
>(
  <T extends FieldValues>(
    { onSubmit, children, defaultValues, schema }: FormProps<T>,
    refForm: ForwardedRef<HTMLFormElement>
  ): JSX.Element => {
    console.log(refForm);

    const methods = useForm<T>({
      defaultValues,
      ...(schema ? { resolver: yupResolver(schema) as Resolver<T> } : {}),
    });

    const handleSubmit = methods.handleSubmit;

    return (
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          ref={refForm}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit as GenericOnSubmit<T>)}
        >
          {children}
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    );
  }
);
```

This code is a TypeScript React component that provides a generic Form component with `forwardRef` support. Here's a breakdown of the code:

- The `GenericOnSubmit` type represents a function that handles form submission and takes the form data and an optional event as parameters.
- The `FormProps` interface defines the props for the Form component, including `onSubmit` (the form submission handler), `defaultValues` (optional initial values for form fields), `children` (the components rendered inside the form), schema (optional validation schema using Yup), and `ref` (optional forwarded `ref` for the form element).
- The `WithForwardRefType` interface extends `React.FC<FormProps<T>>` to define a generic functional component type that supports `forwardRef`. It includes a call signature that allows using the component as a function call.
- The `Form` component is defined using `forwardRef`. It takes a generic parameter `T extends FieldValues` to specify the type of form field values. It receives the `FormProps` as its props, along with the forwarded ref. Inside the component, it initializes the `useForm` hook with the provided options, including default values and schema if available. It also logs the ref to the console. The `handleSubmit` function is extracted from the methods object returned by `useForm`. The component renders a `FormProvider` component to provide the form methods and wraps the form element with the form tag. The `onSubmit` function is called with the correct type using a type assertion, and the children are rendered inside the form.
- Finally, the `Form` component is exported with the `WithForwardRefType` to provide the generic type and `forwardRef` support.

This code allows you to create a generic `Form` component that can be used with different types of form field values and supports forwarding the ref to the form element. It also integrates with `react-hook-form` and `yup` for form validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 4** supports `displayName` if an `interface` is used for the return type of `forwardRef`.

```
import React from "react"

// Redecalare forwardRef
declare module "react" {
  function ComponentToRender<T, P>(props: P, ref: React.ForwardedRef<T>): React.ReactElement | null;
  ComponentToRender.displayName as string;

  function ForwardedComponent<T, P>(props: P & React.RefAttributes<T>): React.ReactElement | null;
  ForwardedComponent.displayName as string;

  function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(
    render: ComponentToRender<T, P>
  ): ForwardedComponent<T, P>;
}
```