# Interface infer type based on a property it defines

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When an interface exposes a generic that simply get's used to type one the properties. Is there a way to "use" that based on inference at a usecase?

Take a look at this:

[image]

> please assume here that the Generic cannot be simply applied, and that the `onClick` will exist.

As you can see, the `is` property of my `TestObject` is a generic, that is statically given. Is there a way to put bounds around this so when the `onClick` wants an argument, it knows that the `is` property is `div` to therefore only allow `value == 'div'`.

My use case for this is in the React world where I want my component to be given a prop that defines its render (`createElement`), but need that to be typesafe for all handlers and attributes it applies. I suppose a generic would work, but that falls apart when sent into `forwardRef`.

Here is an example of what I have currently, and also where my predicament lies.

```
import { AllHTMLAttributes, createElement, forwardRef } from 'react';

interface Props<Element extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>
    extends Omit<AllHTMLAttributes<Element>, 'width' | 'height'> {
    is?: Element;
    className?: string;
}

// There is a little more going on inside the Component, but you get the gist.
const Box = forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props<'div'>>(({ is, children }, ref) =>
    createElement(is, {
        ref,
    }, children));
```

As you can see from there, now the `is` prop is locked to just being a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS currently doesn't support [arbitrary generic value types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) except generic functions. Also, in a variable assignment like `const x`, the compiler cannot infer the type argument for `T` automatically.

In other words, you have to give `TestObject` a concrete type argument: `const x: TestObject<"div">`. Your case still compiles, as the given default `"div"|"a"` for `T` is used, when nothing is specified. Alternatively you could use a factory function to initialize`x`, but here I would just go with the former for simplicity.

---

The issue with `React.forwardRef` is related to above topic, albeit a bit more complex.

`React.forwardRef` [cannot output a generic component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473012/5669456) with current React type definitions - I have mentioned some workarounds in the linked answer. The simplest workaround for you is to use a type assertion:

```
const Box = forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props<keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>>(({ is, children }, ref) =>
  is === undefined ? null : createElement(is, { ref, }, children)) as
  <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(p: Props<T> &
  { ref?: Ref<HTMLElementFrom<T>> }) => ReactElement | null

// this is just a helper to get the corresponding HTMLElement, e.g. "a" -> HTMLAnchorElement
type HTMLElementFrom<K extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = 
  NonNullable<Extract<JSX.IntrinsicElements[K]["ref"], React.RefObject<any>>["current"]>
type AnchorEle = HTMLElementFrom<"a"> // HTMLAnchorElement
```

This will make your `Box` generic and you could create both `div` and `a` Boxes:

```
const aRef = React.createRef<HTMLAnchorElement>()
const jsx1 = <Box is="a" ref={aRef} onClick={e =>{}} />
// is?: "a" | undefined, ref: RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>, onClick?: "a" callback

const divRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
const jsx2 = <Box is="div" ref={divRef} onClick={e =>{}} />
// is?: "div" | undefined, ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>, onClick?: "div" callback
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=24&ssc=90&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCCANoQBIAqAsgDL4wxTABGArjEgM7ZpSpsCihJCCQA7LHABm0AO4ooAE2QTsSlagwCho8cnQwAwhHAQR2zcLFwAvpKhG4Ach56HAbgCwAKC-AxSKBLoSHAACnZg7AA8ZHBIAB5sIvLscADWSACeEBJwAFIAygAaAHQAkmIMIuzAaOba7AB8XnCxCaLJcADyIMAwkUSklDR0DCxsUWQN2A7SwPIwABYOcAA%20jgtIwADmCzAODbjNcMDsAPwAXHBkHp4taIQo7OwAcijCF3Ds9L5bN1ZeXjQJi%20cAAQhA4nAALySGRyRRICSRcjUOpibBhCARSLpLI5AolcrfKo1NEwRoNAAUlLwJy4C2AhHkPBE1mwPAkAEpoU1bscUlDBXBmElEb4kPI4Kc4CJmMQ4JduLwkGTKXTcHAOdgrPTGczRJzuY8jtFWokOrjsnkimUKr5qrVBBZyVSwJdMdjJnAAGRHPAcj5KZFDMkAMTsIGiDQOVm5UIOug0Tu0qxlcsIAM8MAyYGCKKoYYjkQA0mb2ilLfibUTKg6yY1oUdniZnumUIxBJE%20AkoHpIgTbcS68mxOwANrFgC6Y4ARByZ5O1HpikpOowAFZIDCRFAiDLR2doZhQFkwBe87O5ggiNALaCaaFwfOFoyRGcoGcHAD0X6fQ3wN53lAZKZkCVTwCgSiPomMDFEqKBsEG%20YAbe94jjAVKcoCwLwOu7BxAAjI%20kTgpCJxQu%20M6aoiUI4JBiI2CY%20iEDUqS0cE8Y4FYNhfryP78h8lGpiK8hiqY8jsoilyrhuW59MhgFoVoYhTHATEsWgqSCR%20cBoCgxCMOgqSgThcDyMAABuUEwjBcHOIhiLBtQAAillkph2HgXAeFxAATMRpH8hR5kWVRHK0SFSiMSIzGsexPJcTxfG-icgkhVRawiWJEqSRI0nqLBMmbtu%20auRZ7nYOprFpZZVF6QZRleEAA)