# How to write a React component with parameterized props and a forward ref, in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

Minimal example with my best attempt so far:

```js
interface Props<T> {
  foo: T
}

const Component = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, React.PropsWithChildren<Props<???>>>({ foo, children }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {foo}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see in this construction, there's no place to declare the type parameter. How can I express this?

Comment: cant you accept the dynamic parameter during assignment? `Component = <T>React.forwardRef`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React with Typescript -- Generics while using React.forwardRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469229/react-with-typescript-generics-while-using-react-forwardref)