# How do I type a forwardRef?

Tags: typescript, react-native, generics

Similar to [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics) but I have a specific scenario which didn't see to work with the solutions provided there

Also more specific with examples compared to [How do I type my ref correctly in a forwardRef component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496467/how-do-i-type-my-ref-correctly-in-a-forwardref-component)

I am trying to wrap `FlatList` with something that I modified that would ensures that the columns are the same width and I just made a change to allow it to pass a ref in.

Originally I had

```
export function FlatList<ItemT=any>( props : FlatListProps<ItemT>) {
...
}
```

So when I tried to convert it failed, and I had to resort to `any` as follows

```
import {FlatList as RNFlatList} from 'react-native';
...
export const FlatList = forwardRef<RNFlatList<any>, FlatListProps<any>>(
...
}
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
export const FlatList = <ItemT=any,>forwardRef<RNFlatList<ItemT>, FlatListProps<ItemT>>(
...
}
```

Comment: The problem that you are having is that the `forwardRef` makes your component not generic anymore.  I have closed this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469229/react-with-typescript-generics-while-using-react-forwardref which has a very thorough answer explaining multiple solutions. You can also read this blog article: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs/